# How to detect paper end or near to end using thermal printer library in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, thermal-printer

Is there any way to detect paper end or near to end in thermal printer by bluetooth using this library
https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android?

Because I want to save sell after printing.

Comment: I searched the repository with words such as `paper / end / empty / sensor`, but it seems that there is no such function.

Comment: i want to do any thing make to know if printing was done or not to decide to save sale or not

Comment: The library doesn't seem to have any features that can be used for that. You will customize it yourself if necessary.